# How to use play framework 2.4 evolutions?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.4

I have read the documentation about evolutions, but Play framework 2.4 evolutions is not working in my project. The message that asks to confirm the sql script does not appear, and I can`t create script. My model, class User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class User extends Model {
@Id
@Constraints.Required
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private String email;

@Constraints.Required
private String password;

@Constraints.Required
private String firstName;

@Constraints.Required
private String lastName;

@Constraints.Required
private String phone;

@ManyToOne
private Group group;
}
```

Class Group:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "group")
public class Group extends Model {

@Id
@Constraints.Required
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "group")
public List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

I have added this to build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
evolutions,
javaJdbc,
cache,
javaWs,
"org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1201-jdbc41"
)
```

And this to application.conf:

```
# Ebean
ebean.default = ["models.*"]
# Evolutions
# ~~~~~
# You can disable evolutions if needed
play.evolutions.enabled=true
play.evolutions.autoApply=true
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: I will get an exception: **IllegalArgumentException: Was expecting an EntityBean but got a class model.Group** if I want to add a group to database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem. I  the package **model** on **models**.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call your entity "User", it's error prone (many dbs use it for metadata)

Comment: Thanks. I renamed entity.